# Balanced Symbol check using stack in Python

Tags: python, stack

I have been trying to do a balanced symbol problem using python

```
import Stack from Stack 
def parChecker(symbolString):
    s = Stack()
    balanced = True
    index = 0
    while index < len(symbolString) and balanced:
        symbol = symbolString[index]
        if symbol in "([{":
            s.push(symbol)
        else:
            if s.isEmpty():
                balanced = False
            else:
                top = s.pop()
                if not matches(top,symbol):
                   balanced = False
        index = index + 1
    if balanced and s.isEmpty():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def matches(open,close):
    opens = "([{"
    closers = ")]}"
    return opens.index(open) == closers.index(close)


print(parChecker('{{([][])}()}'))
print(parChecker('[{()]'))
print (parChecker('({[})]')     # --- THis is balanced but returns false
```

But this return false to the input ([{)}]. This input seems to be balanced but the output returned is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the syntax for the import statement at the very top doesn't look right. Secondly, which package are you importing the Stack class from?

Coming to your question, I would argue that the ({[})] is not really balanced. Judging from the algorithm, the way it would work is as follows.

Step 1. Push ( to the stack

Step 2. Take the next character. Is it the opposite of the item at the top of the stack? No. Push { to the stack. Stack: ({

Step 3. Take the next character. Is it the opposite of the item at the top of the stack? No.Push [ to the stack. Stack: ({[

Step 4. Take the next character. Is it the opposite of the item at the top of the stack? No. Push } to the stack.

Step 5. And so on, until the stack is ({[})]

On the contrary, if the input were ({[]}), after step 4, the stack would have been ({ since ] would have popped [ from the stack. After step 5, it would be (, and after step 6, it would be empty.

Comment: Is there a condition for this problem that the order of the brackets must be correct?

Comment: I have made a class Stack and have defined all the stack functions in that class. I am importing the same to my program. This program is working fine only the third input is coming false. But I think it might be that we need to put the order of brackets in a correct order!

Comment: @ShreyaSrivastava, the condition for balance should be that the order matters. Otherwise, the solution becomes rather trivial, i.e. count the number of { and the number of }. If the counts are equal, then the input is balanced.

Comment: Okay .. Thank you for the help :)